How to make Semantic Kernel look up information on website?
I know that I can use the WebSearchEnginePlugin to make Semantic Kernel look up general information by using Fx the Bing or Google Connector like this:
kernel.ImportPluginFromObject(new WebSearchEnginePlugin(new BingConnector("SECRET")));

But how can I make Semantic Kernel look up information on a specific website? Let's say I want it to go to fx a canteen website like this https://gn.foodbycoor.dk/lautrupbjerg-6/en/weekmenu so it can tell me what's for lunch tomorrow?
Maybe I should create a KernelFunction that does the lppkup and return the menu of the given day?
EDIT:
My solution, inspired by jeb's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78705767/2787333. It gets all the data from html and json files and can answer what the menu is, when the canteen is open and who the staff is. I'll post it on GitHub soon.
kernel.ImportPluginFromType<GetCanteenPlugin>(); 
var settings = new OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings() {ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions}; 
var chatService = kernel.GetRequiredService<IChatCompletionService>();
var chatHistory = new ChatHistory();
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Q: ");
    chatHistory.AddUserMessage(Console.ReadLine());
    var answer = await chatService.GetChatMessageContentAsync(chatHistory, settings, kernel);
    Console.WriteLine($"A: {answer}");
    chatHistory.Add(answer);
}

class GetCanteenPlugin
{
    [KernelFunction]
    public string GetMenu() {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.Load("CanteenWebsite/Menu.html");
        return htmlDoc.Text;
    }

    [KernelFunction]
    public string GetOpeningHours() {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.Load("CanteenWebsite/OpeningHours.html");
        return htmlDoc.Text;
    }
    
    [KernelFunction]
    public string GetStaff() {
        var staff = File.ReadAllText("CanteenWebsite/Staff.json");
        return staff;
    }
}


Please Note that the [Description] Attribute is important. That's how the LLM knows about your function.

Yea, you are right. A description attribute is good, but it actually seems like it can use the function name and argument names to generate context if there is not a description. I'm not sure what 'best practice' is.

You can define a Plugin to get the information from the website an pass it to the LLM.
var kernelBuilder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();
var kernel = kernelBuilder
    .AddHuggingFaceChatCompletion(
        "phi3",
        new Uri("http://localhost:11434"),
        apiKey: null)
    .Build();

kernel.Plugins.AddFromType<GetMenuPlugin>("MenuPlugin");

var menu = await kernel.Plugins.GetFunction("MenuPlugin", "get_menu")
    .InvokeAsync(kernel);

Console.WriteLine(menu);

ChatHistory chatHistory = new ChatHistory("The menu is:\n" + menu);
chatHistory.AddUserMessage("What is the menu for thursday? Make a short answer");

IChatCompletionService chatCompletionService = kernel.GetRequiredService<IChatCompletionService>();
var result = await chatCompletionService.GetChatMessageContentAsync(chatHistory);

Console.WriteLine("Answer:");
Console.WriteLine(result);

Plugin:
public class GetMenuPlugin
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new();

    [KernelFunction("get_menu")]
    [Description("Gets the menu for each day from the website")]
    [return: Description("website as string")]
    public async Task<string> GetMenuAsync()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://gn.foodbycoor.dk/lautrupbjerg-6/en/weekmenu");

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(response);

        // Parse the HTML to find the div with id 'new-two-week-menu' using HtmlAgilityPack
        var menuNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='new-two-week-menu']");
        if (menuNode != null)
        {
            return menuNode.InnerText.Replace("\t", "").Trim();
        }

        return "Menu not found";
    }
}

Packages used:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.61" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel" Version="1.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.HuggingFace" Version="1.15.1-preview" />
  </ItemGroup>


Thanks a lot. I'll try it out early next week and get back with the result

Ah, ok I think I understnd what you are doing. You are getting the website content and adding it to the chat history. But, do I even need to create a plugin for that? Couldn't I just read the website content with a HttpClient and add it to the Chat History without a plugin?

In this concrete example you could do it directly, yes. But then you lose the benefits of using plugings for future use.

Let's say you have 3 methods. GetMenu(), GetOpeningHours(), GetHolidays(). Of course you could get all information and pass it to the LLM. But with a plugin you could have the LLM figure out itself what method to call based on the users question. Plugins are a basic building block of semantic kernel. Hope that clears ist a bit.

Ah, that makes sense
